# TSQL Fulltext search of word containing 1 digit and 1 letter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

Searching fulltext indexed table for word "1F"

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(50) = N'"1F"'

SELECT *
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
WHERE CONTAINS(name, @name)
```

```
bla bla F bla
results F
```

Returns all records where even one separate letter "F". The "1" can be 0...9 with no difference in result. And not returns "1F"

What is wrong?

Comment: Does full text even work with a 2 char string?

Comment: Yes. Even with 1 char

Comment: Check your FTS stoplist

Comment: select * from  sys.fulltext_stoplists
(0 row(s) affected)